# Can't get both filename of csv and its content with async read inside zip

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv, jszip

I'm trying to code a function that loads a zip file containing multiple other zip files, iterate through those and extract all the csv files found to merge and extract the result into one aggregated csv. The problem I ran into is that I can't map the content of the csv to its filename or directory with async. Here's a snippet where myzip2 is a JSZIP object, files is a dictionary of the filenames and csvfiles is my output array.

```
    for (var key in files) {
        if ( files[key].name.includes('.csv') ) {
            myzip2.file( files[key].name ).async("string").then( function(result) {
                csvfiles.push( $.csv.toArrays(result) ); // contains the csv content
                csvfiles.push( files[key].name ); // undefined in async
            });
        )
    )
```

I would like to push both the csv content and the filename at the same time, but the filename is undefined inside the function. How can I get it? I haven't had much chance googling my issue, I probably lack the correct wording.

Thanks

---

If anyone runs into the same problem, matching the filename to the content is a closure issue fixed by arrow functions but matching the correct zipfile name is an issue with JSZip appending to the current object. Use `new JSZip()` if you need to clear the old one.

Full code, zipfiles is a list of zipfiles name contained inside the mainzip

```js
var csvfiles = []
for (var i = 0; i < zipfiles.length; i++) {

    let thiszipname = zipfiles[i];
    let thiszip = mainzip.file( thiszipname ).async("blob");

    var newzip = new JSZip();
    newzip.loadAsync( thiszip ).then(
        subzip => {
            let subfiles = subzip.files;
            Object.keys(subfiles).forEach( filename => {

                if ( filename.includes('.csv') ) {
                    subzip.file( filename ).async("string").then(
                        readData => {
                            var obj = $.csv.toObjects(readData); // works great
                            obj['csvfile'] = filename            // correct file
                            obj['zipfile'] = thiszipname;        // incorrect zipfile...
                            csvfiles.push( obj );
                        }
                    );
                }
            })

        }
    )
} console.log(csvfiles)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to the lexical scope of the `files` variable. It is not related to `async`.

> A closure is the combination of a function bundled together (enclosed) with references to its surrounding state (the lexical environment). In other words, a closure gives you access to an outer function’s scope from an inner function. In JavaScript, closures are created every time a function is created, at function creation time.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

---

As you are doing this in the loop, you need to take care of the "closure in loop" problem.

Please check out the section "**Creating closures in loops: A common mistake**" following the same link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures

---

You should replace your anonymous function with an arrow function and it will work.

```js
for (var key in files) {
    // It's important to set the value of the `files[key]` to the separate variable.
    // Because otherwise the last element of the `files` will be captured in the closure for the expression `files[key]`.
    const fileName = files[key].name;
    myzip2
        .file(fileName)
        .async("string")
        // Arrow function `result => {}` creates a closure that captures `fileName` variable from the external scope
        .then(result => {
            csvfiles.push($.csv.toArrays(result));
            csvfiles.push(fileName);
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The filename is not undefined anymore, but it somehow doesn't match the correct filename. I'm getting filenames that have nothing to do with what's stored in result (even non-csv files even though this instruction is in an if statement`if ( files[key].name.includes('.csv') ) `). Any idea why the mismatch? I feel like the key was changed in the meantime because of async

Comment: @Philippe, are you doing it in the loop?

Comment: Yes, there is a loop, it might be relevant,`for (var key in files) {
       if ( files[key].name.includes('.csv') ) {
        myzip2.[...] `

Comment: It's definitely relevant. Please update your question with a loop, I'll update the answer. It's related to the loops and closure.

Comment: @Philippe, I updated the answer. Check the solution out. Please accept and upvote the answer if it solves your problems.

Comment: Hi, I don't want to create a new question just for this but I still have issues with closure. I am using arrow function and I can indeed map the csv content to the correct csv filename, but I somehow can't map it to the correct zipfile name. I edited my question to provide the context around this code

Comment: @Philippe, you need to transform your inner anonymous function into an arrow function. This will make the `thiszipname` captured correctly in the closure which is in the loop. Please ping me here again if you have any related questions.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try but arrow function didn't do it. I replaced every possible "function" by an arrow function and the error is still the same.. Any clue what is causing that if it's not closure?

Comment: Problem fixed, this was because of JSZip object appending to the current archive (and not closing and creating a new one). Thanks a lot for your help, I couldn't have done it without you :)